# Unable to use assets in url() in scss after upgrading to Angular 10

Tags: angular

I upgraded my Angular application from v9 to v10. Almost everything worked but all my images used in `url("assets/images/some/path/image.png")` started to throw the exception-

```
ERROR in ./src/app/pages/about-us/about-us.component.scss
Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: /Users/shashank/Projects/curika/temp-ssr/src/app/pages/about-us/about-us.component.scss:4:20: Can't resolve './assets/images/about-us.png' in '/Users/shashank/Projects/curika/temp-ssr/src/app/pages/about-us'

  2 |   display: block;
  3 |   min-height: 500px;
> 4 |   background: url("./assets/images/about-us.png") no-repeat center;
    |                    ^
  5 | }
```

[image: Angular 10 error of assets]

I tried various old links but none worked.

1. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12797
2. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32811

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**Not really sure what's changed in Angular 10?**

But I found three solutions. The first solution I knew will work but that's time taking to implement in an **existing** mid-size application. But if you have only a few assets to fix, you should go for the first solution only.

## Solution 1 - Using relative assets path (Recommended)

The solution is to use the relative path (from your `.scss` file) of your assets. Basically adding `../` until the `assets` folder is reached.

```css
:host {
    display: block;
    min-height: 500px;
    // Using relative path
    background: url('../../../assets/images/about-us.png') no-repeat center;
}
```

### Pros

1. This approach enables the hashing of your static assets. Once your application is built (using `ng build --prod`), your asset URL will be replaced with an MD5 hash to burst the caching.

   So your URL

   ```css
   background: url('../../../assets/images/about-us.png') no-repeat center;
   ```

   will be replaced as

   ```css
   background: url('about-us.add9979f32e1c969e6f8.png') no-repeat center;
   ```

   This is basically an MD5 checksum of the content of the image. So basically, when the image changes even by one pixel, this checksum will be changed by Angular. This helps you to burst caching in future when you change your image while keeping the file name the same.

   Read more [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/) for knowledge.
2. IDE (I use IntelliJ IDEA) does not show errors of the assets in your SCSS files that means if the file path is wrong, IDE will tell you in advance.

   [image: IDE Errors Gone]
3. You get the directory linking. That means if I press Ctrl & click on a directory in the URL above, IDE will open up that directory.

### Cons

1. (**Manageable**) This might be a cumbersome approach as the developer has to write the asset which needs to be relative to the assets folder.
2. (**Manageable**) The hashed asset (image in this case) will be copied to the root folder in the build (i.e. `dist` by default) directory which might fail your any kind of URL rules (for example, caching rules). So instead of-

   ```
   https://example.com/assets/images/about-us.png
   ```

   the following URL will be used-

   ```
   https://example.com/about-us.add9979f32e1c969e6f8.png
   ```
3. (**Manageable**) If you change the path of your component, you have to change the image URL as well.

---

## Solution 2 - Quick Fix

Based on the answer posted here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10004#issuecomment-375969537, adding `/` in front of the URL worked.

```css
:host {
    display: block;
    min-height: 500px;
    background: url('/assets/images/about-us.png') no-repeat center;
}
```

### Pros

1. You do not have to add many `../` prefixes to make it a relative URL.
2. If you change the path of your component SCSS file, you don't have to change the path of your assets in `url("")`.

### Cons

1. The second solution will not work in the production build if `--base-href` is used (as stated [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18013#issuecomment-650721874)). [angular-cli#18043](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18043).
2. Your IDE keeps showing the path error even if the path is correct.

   [image: IDE path error]
3. You do not get the hashed URLs to burst the cache (unlike solution 1)

---

## Solution 3 - Fooling the Angular CLI processor (not recommended)

I looked into the CLI code & figured out that if a URL starts with `^`, Angular ignores the asset by bypassing the URL.

```css
:host {
    display: block;
    min-height: 500px;
    background: url('^assets/images/about-us.png') no-repeat center;
}
```

Source code- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/v10.0.0/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/postcss-cli-resources.ts#L72

### Pros

1. You do not have to add many `../` prefixes to make it a relative URL.
2. If you change the path of your component SCSS file, you don't have to change the path of your assets in `url("")`.

### Cons

1. This solution might get removed in the future releases as stated by one of the Angular CLI developers in [#18013 (comment)](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18013#issuecomment-649373940)

Comment: Hi. one question. Are you sure the first solution will work after compilation?
Because after `ng build` the structure of the folders will be changed.
Thank you for the 2-nd solution I didn't know that one I always used the 3-rd solution.

Comment: Yes @AshotAleqsanyan all the solution will work for `ng build --prod`. Even the first solution has a benefit. I'm going to update the same in the answer.

Comment: What if we wanted the background url to change based on something like language?background: url('../../../assets/en/images/common-bg.png') no-repeat center; or background: url('../../../assets/fr/images/common-bg.png') no-repeat center;  Also, we want to make the path a scss variable; because we want different components to reference the same file. But different components may be at different folder levels , so the relative path from the component scss to common-bg.png will be different. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @milesmeow I think, in that case, you have to go with the solution 2.

Comment: We tried that and it didn't work for us.  What we ended up doing is to define an $assetPath variable and put it in the appropriate scss files that uses a file in that assets folder.  We found that the relative path is relative to the scss file that is referencing the asset.

Comment: So I have to go and literally change 100+ references in our (enterprise) app... Also, referencing assets by a variable is also a nightmare now? `$nav-logo-background: url('assets/Images/my-logo.svg') center no-repeat`? I don't understand why we cant reference `assets/...`, and it redirects to the location specified in the angular.json file?

Comment: Yes @JohanAspeling that's why I mentioned *Not really sure what's changed in Angular 10?*. I didn't get time to dig deeper.

Comment: No I mean your post helped a lot and I'm grateful for it - it just seems trivial to have to go through the effort to fix something like this in all your scss files. I remember I had a similar issue a while ago with another Angular upgrade, and I had to specify a location via the `stylePreprocessorOptions` options in the `angular.json` file, and that fixed my problem back then [link for reference](https://codebriefly.com/handling-css-preprocessors-angular-5/#_SCSS_Include_Paths). But now, for some reason that doesn't even work anymore.

Comment: Got your point @JohanAspeling. I'm glad that it helped you. I read your previous reference, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal I'm using sprite with hash code identifier in my scss files. After upgrading to Angular 10, hash code stopped coming in URL, any thoughts ?

Angular 8  - url(sprite.svg#search) no-repeat
Angular 10 - url(sprite.svg) no-repeat

Comment: What do you mean by hash code identifier?

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal For ex. in Angular 8 - background: url(sprite.svg#search) was working good, nbt now in Angular 10, after adding relative path after hash part is removed. so, right now in Angular 10, we getting background : url(sprite.svg) only.

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal - For more details - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65283942/how-to-handle-hashed-assets-with-sprite-svg-in-angular-10

Comment: Have you tried solution# 2 & solution# 3?

Answer (score 10):

If your `assets` folder is inside `src` folder then try this:

```css
background: url("~src/assets/images/some/path/image.png")
```

This solution it will work with `base-href`

Comment: `ng build` will copy an image from assets to a root folder