# How to handle hashed assets with sprite.svg in Angular 10

Tags: angular, svg, angular-cli, sprite

Recently, we updated our Angular application **from version 8 to version 10**, where we add fixes to assets folder for having relative path and it work perfectly fine for all images except sprite icons.

We having [svg-fragment-identifiers](https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/), where hash code is used as identifiers for specific to SVG icon from SPRITE file.

```
In Angular 8 - background: url(sprite.60bf8dc8eb06ec7972fe.svg#search) no-repeat
In Angular 10 - background: url(sprite.60bf8dc8eb06ec7972fe.svg) no-repeat
```

Problem - After hash part is missed in Angular 10, which creating issue for not showing any icon image from sprite