# BaseHref not working in scss files when updating to Angular 11

Tags: angular

I updated my Angular version profect from 9 to 11 and I got and issue when compiling the project with a baseHref. I already change from setting the baseHref in the command like --base-href to the angular.json file and set the options of the build and set "baseHref": "/baseHref/". When I check the browser Requests I have noticed that the images that are requested from the scss are not requested with the baseHref. I tried setting the baseHref and also the deployUrl but doesn't work.

Comment: found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619062/unable-to-use-assets-in-url-in-scss-after-upgrading-to-angular-10/62619147#62619147

Answer (score 0):

In index.html file change

```
<base href="/">
```

to

```
<base href="./">
```

and try
`ng build --prod --base-href ./`